# jQuery login button is opening a login window, but if javascript is off

Tags: jquery

I have a login button, it is a link.
When I click on it, it slides down a little window that contains a login form.

Now, what I want to do is, if browser doesn't support the javascript code (JS is offline), then it will go to the link.

I need to find a way to disable links of that button ID on click, JS will do that, and when JS is off, it will just pass like normal.

This is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#loginToggler").click(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#login_block").slideToggle("slow");
            }, 100);
        });
        $("#closeLogin").click(function() {
            $("#login_block").slideUp("fast");
        });
    });

            <li id="last-child"><a href="#"><div id="login"></div></a></li>
```

What can I do there to do this?

Comment: For that one person with JavaScript disabled, why don't you make the form always visible and hide and then animate it with JavaScript instead?

Comment: I rather to send them to the actual login page instead, that's how my design is built.

Comment: you can use the <noscript> tag

Comment: Change the href of your link to point to your actual login page. `<a href="login.php"><div id="login"></div></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make the login  a normal hyperlink
2. In your JQuery, change the href attribute of the hyperlink so it no longer links to anything
3. Add in your slide out functionality

You can use the .attr function to make it so that it doesn't link directly to the login page anymore in the javascript. So it would be something like...

```
<li id="last-child"><a href="loginpageurl" id="loginbutton"><div id="login"></div></a></li>

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#loginbutton").attr("href","#");
    $("#loginToggler").click(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#login_block").slideToggle("slow");
        }, 100);
    });
    $("#closeLogin").click(function() {
        $("#login_block").slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

Adjust identifiers as appropriate.

so if there's no javascript it will behave like a normal link. When there is, the link will go nowhere and the slide out functionality will be enabled.

Comment: Doesn't function. I think Attr was renamed to something else, if I remember correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Put the actual link in the `href=""` and add `onclick="return false;"` to the `a` tag.

Ie:

```
<li id="last-child"><a href="/login.php" onclick="return false;"><div id="login"></div></a></li>
```

The "return false" tells the browser not to follow the link if JavaScript is enabled. If JavaScript isn't enabled, the "onclick" event won't fire and the "return false" has no effect.

Comment: If I will return false, the login won't appear cause I am returning the js i think, well it doesnt open.

Comment: Well in that case you can create a function to show your login popup and call it in the onclick before return false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***e.preventDefault()*** and have your href for the Login link go to the login page.

**If javascript is enabled:**

A user clicks on the link the login_block will slide down and then e.preventDefault() is called to prevent the href location from being used.

**If javascript is disabled:**

The href location will be used and the user will be taken to the login page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     $("#loginToggler").click(function() {
          $("#login_block").slideToggle("slow");
          e.preventDefault();
     });
     $("#closeLogin").click(function() {
          $("#login_block").slideUp("fast");
     });
});

<li id="last-child">
     <a href="http://www.Somesite.com/Login">
          <div id="login"></div>
     </a>
</li>
```